# Is there anyway of having a for loop wait until an interval have cleared

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, for-loop, intervals

I have a for loop running agains a node list. I am trying to run through the node list and trigger a click then i set an interval to wait for a popup then i want to trigger a click within the popup.

My issue is i need each iteration to wait until the popup is loaded and the item in the popup as been clicked before going to the next iteration. Hope this makes sense.

Here is my code.

```
let checkSteats = () => {
  const seats = document.querySelectorAll(seatSectionSelector);
  if (seats.length < maxSeatCount) {
    maxSeatCount = seats.length;
  }

  if (seats.length > 0) {

    [].forEach.call(seats, (seat, index) => {
  /**
   * WE NEED TO CLICK WAIT FOR A CHANGE IN THE RESPONSE OR POP UP BEFORE WE GO INTO THE NEXT ITERATION
   */
  console.log(seat)
  if ((index+1) <= maxSeatCount) {

    seat.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        buttons: 1
      })
    );

    const popupInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const popupBtn = document.querySelector('.ticket-option__btn');

      if (popupBtn) {
        popupBtn.click();
        clearInterval(popupInterval);
      }
    }, 100)


  } 
}); 

} 
};
```

Comment: You should not be using a loop for this. Should be a method that shifts() the item from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a basic queue where you pull the item off from the front of the array with shift()

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function nextItem() {
  var item = myArray.shift();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(item);
    if (myArray.length) nextItem();
  }, 1000)
}
nextItem()
```

So in your case, you would call nextItem() when you clear the interval. You can get shift by converting the html collection to an array

```
const seats = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(seatSectionSelector));
function nextItem() {
  var seat = seats.shift();
  seat.dispatchEvent(...);
  const popupInterval = setInterval(() => {
    ...
    if (popupBtn) {
      ...
      if (seats.length) nextItem();
    }
```

Comment: Not a 100% on how to incorporate that into my code.

Comment: Got it working mate - thank you very much you a complete life saver! I owe you one!!!